# Stop text pushing down menu

Tags: css, menu

On a dev site there is some rotating text at the top of the screen. The site is http 109.108.155.82

I have sped this up to explain the issue. The text is using different number of characters and the long text is pushing the menu down. Is there anyway to keep it the same?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/209357)

Comment: Please, show us some code to better identify the problem.

Comment: put it in jsFiddle and I will take a look though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the height of the `<ul id="tips">` to the max height of the largest content such as

```
#tips
{
height: 150px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
#tips, #tips li {
    height: 100px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
```

obviously change the height to your desired number, and also limit the characters you display in the li itself to avoid text being cut off.

Jeroen